# How to input data from file into a matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, input

I've been searching everywhere for this answer but I can't seem to find it. I was given an assignment to make a program which can add and subtract matrix. But the data for the matrix need to be input from a file (txt file).

Comment: May you give an example of the file which you want to get the data from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'm guess that your input file, I'll call it `input.txt`, has a structure like:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
```

Then, I would recommend that you do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// ...

int main(int argc, char* argc[])
{
    // ...
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
    std::vector<int> row;

    // ...

    char delim = ' ';

    while(std::getline(std::cin, row, delim)
    {
        matrix.push_back(row)
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Then input your file like:

```
program < input.txt
```

That should do the trick, but I didn't test it :)

Happy coding!